# Formatter function not found despite being properly assigned in XML view

Tags: sapui5

Hello SAPUI5 Developers,

I have a problem and this is the error I get:

> formatter function .formatter.delivery not found!

This is my view/App.view.xml:

```xml
<firstStatus>
  <ObjectStatus text="{ 
    parts : [ 
      { path: 'WeightUnit' },
      { path: 'WeightMeasure' }
    ], 
    formatter : '.formatter.delivery' 
  }" />
</firstStatus>
```

And this is my model/formatter.js:

```js
sap.ui.define([], function() {
  "use strict";

  return {
    delivery: function(/*...*/) {
      // ...
    }
  };
});
```

And this is my controller/App.controller.js

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/m/MessageToast",
  "opensap/myapp/model/formatter"
], function (Controller, MessageToast, formatter) {
  "use strict";
        
  return Controller.extend("opensap.myapp.controller.App", {
    formatter: formatter,
    // ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
controllerName="opensap.myapp.controller.App"
```

Needed to be added in App.view.xml.

Comment: Please accept your own answer (click on the check mark) to let others know that this issue is now resolved.